# Slack Api Oauth - Login URL

Tags: java, oauth, slack-api

Can any one suggest me an url with username and password to enable login into slack account from my app?
I'm currently using this URL, but it will land up on Login page.
https://qurater.slack.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=4309263747.14633076871&scope=read&team=T04937RMZ

Comment: Did you found a solution? I am researching the same subject now. Thank you.